# How to load your own GUI app without the rest of the GUI in Linux?

Tags: boot, startup, gui

Is there a way to load my own GUI app without the rest of the GUI in Linux?  It's something like running Winamp only, and practically turning your PC into a music player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Windows has a kiosk mode that can be used to start an application, usually a web browser, as the only running app, and not loading the full window manager.  I don't know that it will work with Winamp, but you could try (from the console):

```
startx /path/to/winamp --kiosk
```

Comment: Woah~  Thank you so much.  Will try.

Comment: Actually, the `--kiosk` option here has nothing to do with `startx`: it is interpreted as an option for `/path/to/winamp` instead. But the idea still works: `startx <some GUI application [with maybe options]>` makes `startx` to start only the specified application and a bare X11 server for it, nothing more. In this way, not even a window manager is started unless you specifically say so, and so the "window decorations" (usually the top bar and borders) you may be used to seeing will be omitted. This will also severely limit the possibilities to move or resize the windows.